# Linking autocomplete results

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I've put together a very basic autocomplete searchbox which is able to return names from a database query into a dropdown list, but am having trouble linking these to the appropriate profiles.

Expected result: The user begins to type a staff members name, the input is populated with matched staff and their department and then the user can click on the name of the staff member that they are searching for in order to visit their profile. If possible, I'd also like a picture of the staff member to appear next to their name.

I'm very new to Javascript and it's taken me a very long time to get to this point and I lack the wherewithal to know where to begin tackling the next step. I'd really appreciate being pointed in the right direction!

Searchbox:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script> $(function() {
    var url = '/search.php' + "?action=search";

    $( "#resizedtextbox" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 3,
      source: url,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#resizedtextbox" ).val( ui.item.name );
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#name" ).val( ui.item.name );
        $( "#dpt" ).val( ui.item.dpt );
        $( "#link" ).html( ui.item.link );
        $( "#link" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.image );

        return false;
      }
    })
.autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
        .append('<a href="/' + item.link + '"><table><tr><td width= "5%"><img src="/' + item.link + '/profilepicture.jpg" width=100%></td><td width=95%>' + item.name + '<br>(' + item.dpt + ')</a></td></tr></table>')
        .appendTo(ul);
};
  });</script>

<div class="searchbar" id="searchbar">
<table width=100%><tr><td width= 95.5%><input type="text" name="resizedtextbox" id="resizedtextbox" class="resizedtextbox" placeholder="Search for a staff member..."></td>
<td width=4%><img src='searchbutton.png' width= 40px height= 40px></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Search.php

```
<?php 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/config.php";
require_once "$path";?>


<?php
    $id = $_GET["term"]; 
    $searchquery = "

    SELECT staff_member as name, profile_url as link, 
    department as dpt FROM staff_a
    WHERE staff_member LIKE '%".$id."%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name as name, profile_url as link, 
    department as dpt FROM staff_b
    WHERE name LIKE '%".$id."%'
    ";
        $result = $conn->query($searchquery);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $row;

}
//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Effectively, what I'd like to return to my input box is something along the lines of this...

```
<table><tr><td><a href="$row[link]"><img src="/site/$row[link]/profilepicture.jpeg">$row[name] ($row[department])</a></td></tr></table>
```

Edit: it seems that the information here - [Getting jQuery autocomplete to display results as links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128952/getting-jquery-autocomplete-to-display-results-as-links) may be what I need, but the original poster didn't post the code for their search page and so I'm a little lost as to how to implement the solution.

Edit2: managed to get it working with quite a bit of tweaking and have edited the above code with the correct answer on the off chance somebody stumbles upon this in the future.

My only issue now is that I'd like the user to be taken to the correct profile when they hit enter on the correct staff member as well as when they click with the cursor (at present, hitting enter just fills the textbox with the staff member's name).

Answer (score 1):

**Server side**: You need to respond all necessary fields for each user from query result:

```php
<?php

//...

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = [
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'value' => $row['name'], // value is required for autocomplete to display
        'department' => $row['department'],
        'link' => $row['link'],
        'id' => $row['id'],

        // ...
    ];
}
```

Your response should look like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "value": "John",
    "link": "#john",
    "department": "d1"
  },
  ...
]
```

**Client side**:

- Add an event `select` to handle when user selects an item from suggestion, this will update the DOM to fill employee name, image, ...

```js
$(function() {
  $("#resizedtextbox").autocomplete({
    source: 'search.php',
    // trigger when user clicks item
    select: function(e, ui) {
      console.log(ui);
      let user = ui.item;
      // update DOM
      $('#name').text(user.name);
      $('#department').text(user.department);
      // other fields: image, link...
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="searchbar" id="searchbar">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle"><input type="text" name="resizedtextbox" id="resizedtextbox" class="resizedtextbox" placeholder="Search for a staff member..."></td>
      <td align="right">
        <span id="name"></span>
        <span id="department"></span>
        <img id="avatar" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40" width="40" height="40" style="vertical-align: middle" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c4wbrkt0/

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I actually cobbled together a working solution while waiting for people to answer. It's probably not as eloquent as your solution, but it seems to do the job. All the same, I really appreciate you taking the time to work on this!